# Working with Cordova Sqlite plugin in ionic 2

Tags: database, sqlite, cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic2

I'm new to ionic 2 development (haven't worked with ionic-1 either).

I'm trying to use cordova sqlite plugin in the application. I followed [Use SQLite in Ionic 2](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/12/use-sqlite-in-ionic-2-instead-of-local-storage/) link. Was able to add the plugin into to project using following command.

> $ ionic plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage

After deploying the app on real device data.db was created and opened and also the `people`table was created successfully. 
Following is the log from the Xcode :

> 2016-10-17 16:29:16.435992 SqlProject[238:3982] -[SQLitePlugin pluginInitialize] [Line 67] no cloud sync at path: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DFDADD59-D48E-4D4C-B8F0-23EEDE169471/Library/LocalDatabase
>   2016-10-17 16:29:16.436138 SqlProject[238:4034] -[SQLitePlugin openNow:] [Line 137] open full db path: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DFDADD59-D48E-4D4C-B8F0-23EEDE169471/Library/LocalDatabase/data.db
>   2016-10-17 16:29:16.443765 SqlProject[238:4034] -[SQLitePlugin openNow:] [Line 163] Good news: SQLite is thread safe!
>   2016-10-17 16:29:16.448487 SqlProject[238:3982] **OPEN database: data.db - OK**
>   2016-10-17 16:29:16.463667 SqlProject[238:3982] **TABLE CREATED:**  [object Object]

**Code for Opening Database:**

> import { SQLite } from 'ionic-native';

```
 constructor(platform: Platform) {
   platform.ready().then(() => {
   StatusBar.styleDefault();

   let database = new SQLite();
        database.openDatabase({
            name: "data.db",
            location: "default"
        }).then(() => {
            database.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT)", {}).then((data) => {
                console.log("TABLE CREATED: ", data);

            }, (error) => {
                console.error("Unable to create table", error);

            })
        }, (error) => {

            console.error("Unable to open database", error);
        });
   });
}
```

But, now I'm getting error while **Inserting** and **Fetching** the records from the db.

```
 public add() {

 console.log("Inside the add function- ");

 this.database.executeSql("INSERT INTO people (firstname, lastname) VALUES (?, ?)", ['mahesh', 'bhalerao']).then((data) => {

   console.log("INSERTED: " + JSON.stringify(data));

 }, (error) => {
   console.log("ERROR: " + JSON);
 });
}

 public fetchRecords() {

    this.database.executeSql("SELECT * FROM people", []).then((data) => {
               alert("executeSql refresh function success");

        this.people = [];

        if(data.rows.length > 0) {
            for(var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
                this.people.push({firstname: data.rows.item(i).firstname, lastname: data.rows.item(i).lastname});
            }
        }
    }, (error) => {
        console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(error.err));
    });
}
```

I'm getting undefined error.

> ERROR: undefined

Not sure what's going wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that this plugin supports promises? If I recall it right you have to use a success callback which returns a result set. Can you show please show more relevant code (like what is this.database and how it is opened and handled)

Comment: @Fylax I have added the relevant to for opening the database.

Answer (score 0):

First snippet, fifth line: you have `let database = new SQLite();`; you create the database onto the disk (if it doesn't exists yet) and then you quit from contructor.

Due to the scoping of `let`, once you exit from the costructor, the `database` variable doesn't exists, to the `add` and `fetch` methods it has never existed.

Instead of `let` you should put `database` into an attribute (that is where the methods are looking for it) and then everything should work fine.

In other words you should have a similar code:

```
public database: SQLite //here the attribute

constructor(platform: Platform) {
   platform.ready().then(() => {
   StatusBar.styleDefault();

   this.database = new SQLite(); //here you initialize the attribute instead of a volative variable
   this.database.openDatabase({ //in this block you open an then populate the attribute
            name: "data.db",
            location: "default"
        }).then(() => {
            database.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT)").then((data) => {
                console.log("TABLE CREATED: ", 
            }, (error) => {
                console.error("Unable to create table", error);
            });
        }, (error) => {
            console.error("Unable to open database", error);
        });
   });
}
```