# What is the import statement for cordova-plugin-sqlite-2 in Ionic framework?

Tags: ionic-framework, android-sqlite, cordova-plugins

I am trying to use [cordova-plugin-sqlite-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sqlite-2) plugin in my Ionic app, but I'm not sure how to use its features for opening or creating a database .
What import () statement should I give to use this plugin ?

I have referred this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40085095/working-with-cordova-sqlite-plugin-in-ionic-2) in which 'import { SQLite } from 'ionic-native';
is used , but it is showing error when used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're trying to use sqlite only or some other DB, but I have recently used PouchDB inside my Ionic5+ReactJs+Typescript app, and here is what I did:

1. Install the necessary packages

> npm install pouchdb pouchdb-adapter-cordova-sqlite cordova-plugin-sqlite-2
> @types/pouchdb @ionic-native/sqlite

Please note that @types packages are for typescript support.

2. Create a sample database

> import PouchDB from "pouchdb";
>
> import "cordova-plugin-sqlite-2/dist/sqlite-plugin";
>
> import cordovaSqlitePlugin from "pouchdb-adapter-cordova-sqlite";
>
> PouchDB.plugin(cordovaSqlitePlugin);
>
> let sampleDB = new PouchDB("sampleDatabase", {
> adapter: "cordova-sqlite",
> });

3. After that you can use the database object directly

> sampleDB.post({name: "my first object"});